# Adding listener to onStart vs onCreate

Tags: android, onclicklistener, oncreate, onstart

I'm trying to implement a button listener, and am able to if I do so in the onStart method. When I instead initialize in the onCreate (which I read is good practice), I'm receiving the error "Failed to update a TargetChangeListener"and the app crashes. Here's the main activity:

```
public class EventExampleActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_example);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

    }
    initListeners();
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

private void initListeners() {
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    myButton.setOnClickListener(
        new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                myTextView.setText("Button Pressed!");              
            }

    });
}
...
...
}
```

if it helps, I'm following this tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_and_Example_of_Android_Event_Handling

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: Does `Button` has a `onClickListener` interface? I only know `View.onClickListener`

Comment: @suitianshi I was also surprised at first, but when I tried, it actually refers to `View.OnClickListener` (because `Button extends View`), so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Is your button in the fragment, or the activity?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume `mybutton` is located within your `Fragment`, rather than your `Activity`.

If that is the case, `myButton` is possibly `null` when you call `initListeners()`, because the view hasn't necessarily been created yet.

Fragments aren't guaranteed to be available as soon as you call beginTransaction()...commit(), so that might explain why you can't set your listener straight away. By the time you get to `onStart()` though, your `Fragment` has been created and your button is not null.

Either continue to use the listener in `onStart()`, or set it from within your `Fragment`, after your view has been inflated in the `onCreateView()` method, or anywhere afterwards in the `Fragment Lifecycle` (`onActivitycreated()` is probably the best place).